# How to Set data to second tableview in same Class in swift

Tags: swift

How to Set data to second tableview in same Class in swift.I am using two tables in the the same controller one for dropdown and another for listing. I am unable to set data to second table(listing) in class
as else part is not called in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Thanks in Advance

```
import UIKit
class PunchClockVC: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
     var appdel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    @IBOutlet weak var dropdownTable: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mainTable: UITableView!
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.mainTable.registerClass(PunchClockCustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "PunchClockCustomCell")
        self.dropdownTable.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "dropdowncell")
        self.dropdownTable.hidden = true
                }
 @IBAction func textFieldTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        if self.dropdownTable.hidden == true {
            self.dropdownTable.hidden = false
        }
        else{
            self.dropdownTable.hidden = false
        }
    }

       func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == dropdownTable {
        return jobArrayID.count
    }

    return 8

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if tableView == self.dropdownTable {

         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("dropdowncell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text =  (jobArrayID[indexPath.row] as! String) + "-" + (jobArrayName[indexPath.row] as! String)

        return cell

    }


 else {
        let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PunchClockCustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PunchClockCustomCell

        if indexPath.row == 0
        {
            cell1.jobcell?.font = UIFont(name: "MuseoSlab-500", size: 25.0)
            cell1.locationcell?.font = UIFont(name: "MuseoSlab-500", size: 25.0)
            cell1.timecell?.font = UIFont(name: "MuseoSlab-500", size: 25.0)
            cell1.typecell?.font = UIFont(name: "MuseoSlab-500", size: 25.0)


            cell1.jobcell?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            cell1.locationcell?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            cell1.timecell?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            cell1.typecell?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()


            cell1.jobcell?.text = "Job"
            cell1.locationcell?.text = "Location"
            cell1.timecell?.text = "Time"
            cell1.typecell?.text = "Type"
          //  return cell1

        }
        else {
            cell1.jobcell?.text = "Jobdata"
            cell1.locationcell?.text = "Locationdata"
            cell1.timecell?.text = "Timedata"
            cell1.typecell?.text = "OUT"
          //  return cell1

        }

        return cell1
    }
```

}

Comment: Are you getting any errors? You also need to make sure you have the function that takes care of `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Comment: Are you sure you have your main table's data source set correctly?

Comment: Here's a [useful gist on GitHub for taking care of multiple tableViews in one ViewController](https://gist.github.com/mchirico/50cdb07d20b1b0f73d7c)

Comment: As @PhillipMills said, check your data source, as I can't see any array called `jobArray` in the current view controller

Comment: both tables is set with data source and delegates

Comment: both tables have there data source and delegate connected

Comment: @PhillipMills   'jobArray' is defined properly and working fine for dropdown table, I am facing problem with 'mainTable' data is not setting in this table

Comment: is the problem still persisting ? or is it resolved?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple You need to set it only with cellForRowAtIndexPath method but the main thing to do is you need to code like below

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    if tableView == firstTbaleView 
//outlet given to first tableView
   {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cust1TableViewCell

            cell.imgView.image = images[indexPath.row]
            cell.filtLabel.text  = self.filtersCount[indexPath.row]


            return cell
    }}else {
            let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cust2TableViewCell
            cell2.imgview.image = UIImage(named: colPhotos[indexPath.row])
            cell2.labl.text = colNames[indexPath.row]

//            cell2.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
//            cell2.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
            return cell2


}
```

and that's it you can ask me for any help..

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath is called for 'maintable' but the data is not shown in the tableview

Comment: Never .. If there are two tables in your view and if you are declaring cellfor row then It will run for both tables. It' s delegate method. There are no main/secondary for cellforRow Method. only you have to do is setting conditions for different tables.

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath is called for both tables but I am not getting data in maintable

Comment: if tableView == firstTbaleView   have you gave this condition??

Comment: Yes. I have to load the maintable by default so I putted it in else part. if tableView == dropdown { //do this} else { // do this}.

Answer (score 0):

Lets make this a little safer:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if tableView == self.dropdownTable {
        return jobArray.count
    }
    else if tableView == self.mainTable {
        return =  5
    }
    //Default return 0. This way if references are broken or change, you won't crash
    return 0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView == self.dropdownTable {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("dropdowncell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        //configure your cell
        return cell
    }
    else if tableView == self.mainTable {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PunchClockCustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PunchClockCustomCell
        //configure your cell
        return cell
    }
    //Shouln't ever reach here, but again, if we refactor somewhere then we'll see an error show up before here.
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```